# AngularJS Directive, passing scope objects in post link function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, hyperlink, directive

I have a HTML template which I'm using for an angular directive. I need to fire some javascript on the HTML template after it has been compiled (I need to fire jQuery Steps to make the HTML into a wizard)

**Sample directive HTML:**

```
<div class='example'>{{passThrough.value1}}</div>
```

and my angular directive would be

```
app.directive('accountWizard', function () {
return {
    templateUrl: '../Scripts/angular/directives/templates/AccountWizard.html',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        passThrough: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.bindAccountDirective();
    }
};
```

});

The HTML in the main page would be something like

```
<account-wizard pass-through="angularObject"/>
```

My problem is that the HTML directive, when rendered, simply has "{{passThrough.value1}}" as text inside the div tag, it's not actually compiling the angular object and returning its value.

When debugging in Chrome, I can see the angular object 'passThrough' in the scope parameter of the link function.

I know I need to do something in the link function to compile and render the directive, but I can't find what that needs to be.

All i need is a simple 'you need to use this....' and I'll work out how to do it from Angular documentation.

Basically, let's say `passThrough.value1 = Test Value`, I need my directive HTML to compile to

```
<div class='example'>Test Value</div>
```

and then, I need to run the jQuery steps function on the HTML after the angular object's have been rendered

p.s. the scope.bindAccountDirective() function is a wrapper method for firing jQuery steps.

```
$scope.bindAccountDirective = function () {

        $("#frmShippingAccount.wizard-big").steps({
            bodyTag: "fieldset",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {

                // Always allow going backward even if the current step contains invalid fields!
                if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
                    return true;
                }

                var form = $(this);

                // Clean up if user went backward before
                if (currentIndex < newIndex) {
                    // To remove error styles
                    $(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error", form).remove();
                    $(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error", form).removeClass("error");
                }

                // Disable validation on fields that are disabled or hidden.
                form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";

                // Start validation; Prevent going forward if false
                return form.valid();

            },
            onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {

                var form = $(this);

                // Disable validation on fields that are disabled.
                // At this point it's recommended to do an overall check (mean ignoring only disabled fields)
                form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";

                // Start validation; Prevent form submission if false
                return form.valid();
            },
            onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {

                var form = $("#frmShippingAccount");

                $("#savePrompt h1").text("Saving...");

                $scope.saveShippingAccount($scope.shippingAccount);

            }
        }).validate({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) { }
        });
}
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

Using `$timeout()` in the link function worked perfectly. It waited for AngularJS to render the `passThrough` object as it's value, and *then* fired the `bindAccountDirective()` function.

```
app.directive('accountWizard', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        templateUrl:  '../Scripts/angular/directives/templates/AccountWizard.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            passThrough: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            $timeout(function(){ scope.bindAccountDirective() }, 0 false);
        }
};
```

Comment: Can you try $scope instead of scope?

Comment: That's not the issue here, the scope parameter of the link function actually does contain the scope object, because for directives the scope isn't injected as it normally is with controllers. When I debug inside the link function, scope does actually contain the passThrough object and all it's values. The problem here is that because I'm using the link function, the scope objects don't seem to be passed through and rendered in the HTML template as they usually are. If i remove the link function, the rendering works but obviously my jQuery steps function doesn't fire

Comment: post the code of bindAccountDirective method.

Comment: added in original question

Comment: I found the answer, might not be slick but it works - I'll now see if there's a proper AngularJS way to do this.

Basically, the link function in the directive needed to use a `$timeout()`, to ensure the directive was rendered before firing

Answer (score 0):

Using `$timeout()` in the link function worked perfectly. It waited for AngularJS to render the `passThrough` object as it's value, and then fired the `bindAccountDirective()` function.

```
app.directive('accountWizard', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        templateUrl:  '../Scripts/angular/directives/templates/AccountWizard.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            passThrough: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            $timeout(function(){ scope.bindAccountDirective() }, 0 false);
        }
};
```